# Is my Rep in Stack-Exchange Form?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem

### Premise:

Your reputation is in Stack-Exchange Form if it can be represented by decomposing your medal counts (gold, silver, and bronze counted separately) into their base-10 digits and joining them in any given order, with a few caveats.

While decomposing, each

- Gold medal digit is worth three digits.
- Silver is worth two digits.
- Bronze is one digit.
- Additionally, since SE does not display a medal type if you do not have any, a count of 0 medals for a type will **not** yield a `[0]`.

**Example:**

- `[1 Gold, 2 Silvers, 3 Bronzes]` will decompose into `[1,1,1,2,2,3]`. 321112 and 213121 are two examples of an SE-form number for these medals.
- `[20 Golds, 0 Silvers, 20 Bronzes]` will decompose into `[2,2,2,0,0,0,2,0]`. 20002022 is an SE-form number.
- `[11 Golds, 0 Silvers, 0 Bronzes]` will decompose into `[1,1,1,1,1,1]`. 111111 is the only SE-form number for this.

There will be no leading 0's when considering a SE number. E.g., in the 2nd example above, `00002222 -> 2222` would not be considered a SE-form number for `[20,0,20]`.

### Input/Output:

Input is a list/tuple/array/whatever of `[reputation, gold_medals, silver_medals, bronze_medals]` which are all non-negative integers. This is the assumed order but can be changed. Just make a note in your answer if you do.

Output is any two consistent values for true and false.

### Rules:

- Input will always be valid
- You will always have at least 1 Rep
- You can have no medals at all, which should always return false then.
- The medal counts have no bearing on reality. Having several hundred golds and no bronzes is fine.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest answer in bytes wins.

### Test Cases:

```
#[Rep, Gold, Silver, Bronze] -> Output
[4, 0, 0, 4]       -> True
[1447, 0, 4, 17]   -> True
[74414, 4, 0, 17]  -> True
[4444, 4, 0, 4]    -> True
[4455, 0, 54, 0]   -> True
[5355, 5, 0, 3]    -> True
[53535, 5, 3, 0]   -> True
[4444, 0, 0, 4444] -> True
[444, 4, 0, 0]     -> True
[1234, 0, 0, 1234] -> True
[1234, 0, 0, 4321] -> True

[4444, 1, 0, 1]      -> False
[5555, 5, 0, 55]     -> False
[1234, 1, 23, 4]     -> False
[1, 0, 0, 0]         -> False
[1001001, 0, 10, 10] -> False
```

Comment: so what exactly does reputation do in the context of the challenge?

Comment: @OrangeCherries Mechanically, nothing. It inspired the challenge because I had 1447 rep and 4 silvers, 17 bronzes at the time of writing.

Comment: Is the input flexible besides the order? So could I for example take an input-list `[bronze, silver, gold]` and a separated second input `reputation`?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Yeah that's fine. The only thing I'd say is disallowed is taking input as a list of lists of chars/digits that make up each number.

Comment: Are any truthy/falsy values allowed for output or does it have to be two consistent ones?

Comment: @NickKennedy Two consistent values. (response now sans snark)

Comment: It'd be nice to have an example that isn't just 1s and 0s, I thought the challenge dealt with binary until I read it through a few times. Maybe I'm just slow tho :)

Comment: @ConorO'Brien But the first example is `[1,2,3]`? I changed the 2nd to `[20,0,20]` just so it's more clear at a glance

Comment: @Veskah It is, but the other two examples were 1s and 0s. I was caught up on those lol

Answer (score 12):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>16</s> <s>14</s> <s>13</s> <s>11</s> 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
∞×0KJ‚€{íË
```

Takes the medals input in the order `[bronze, silver, gold]` as first input, and `reputation` as second input.

-1 byte thanks to *@Grimy*.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Uce8w9MNvL0eNcx61LSm@vDaw93//0cbGugAkUEsl6GBAQgBAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##RY0xCsJQDIavIp0z5DV5dOzipEcoHSo6uOhQEMRFHFRwcxEc3AW9hPUk7yLP5KVqCOH/yJ8/y7aZzGdxtX4fXvdhmQ2axXSQla3KsD@LjOF46y44HoXtNewem@7ZnSLEqmJgQMAaKsdcgCuUhfiLCKwolZwG3ov05vQkRMoGpDtKZFc67EWvUojLiSGN/r1Kptz9vbIXcBorBfb0Z4Wc0i4dWASiNjjUxrr@AA).

**Explanation:**

```python
∞           # Push an infinite positive list: [1,2,3,...]
 ×          # Repeat the values in the (implicit) input-list that many times as string
            # (since the input-list contains just 3 values, the rest of the infinite
            #  list is ignored)
  0K        # Remove all 0s (so all "0", "00" and "000")
    J       # Join the strings in the list together
     ‚      # Pair this string with the (implicit) second input
      €{í   # Sort the digits in both strings in descending order
         Ë  # And check if both are now equal
            # (after which the result is output implicitly as result)
```

Comment: `3L` -> `∞` for -1.

Comment: @Grimy Sometimes it's useful that lists are truncated to the smallest one. :) Thanks!

Comment: This is 19 bytes in utf-8, not 10 bytes.

Comment: @LieRyan You're correct, it's indeed 19 bytes in UTF-8. 05AB1E uses (just for example Jelly and Charcoal) [a custom codepage](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage), where every 256 characters it knows is encoded in 1 byte each. The bytes in this 10-byte version in hexadecimal are `\x19\xd7\x30\x4b\x4a\x82\x80\x7b\xec\xcb`: It should be possible to run these hexadecimal bytes with the `--osabie` flag, but I'm not sure how to do so in the 05AB1E Elixir version to be completely honest (but I will ask some others to verify and get back to you with the answer).

Comment: @LieRyan In the 05AB1E (legacy) Python version it could be done [like this](https://tio.run/##PY09CsJAFAZ7T/ERLbTY/ChBERQUvIFlmrebZzaQ5C3JgskNxAt5Cw/hRaIi2E0xzGjq7Ggk512Q9fEm65ec9ck6wBRnyx3Dck85m7KmCnrw3IFahreMi1SVXMumQJwejskJ84oLMsMCrpWipXqL5yN83e4jGytQDRRj9n1hj0/Ih6R54gZvpVkhEuejOCWdcCQd6ZJDN0CpH//9cSRtcn4D) (it's a different program for another challenge of course), but it should give you the idea of how the hexadecimal bytes are run.

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>92</s>  74 bytes

Takes input as `(['gold','silver','bronze'])('rep')`. Returns a Boolean value.

```javascript
b=>r=>[...b.map((n,i)=>n.repeat(+n&&3-i)).join``].sort()+''==[...r].sort()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZHBjsIgGITv@xR7EoiVlALxRI8@gTfXRHSr1lRoaN1kn75LoZU1abEhfwj5OjMMN/kjm5Mp63al9HfRnUV3FLkR@Q5jfMR3WUOokhKJXGFT1IVs4VItFnRVIoRvulSHwx432rQQLQEQov/NjCfdSatGVwWu9AWCrXm011@APv6fnuEOpCD59IOBPYJ2ohmI9YOsHUUYW0@B7Kk2gOw9Ofjab9aaD7QHOZ8C@VOQOo7TCEeDnuUon3X2CftssZDhMmNGFlckGfWKbhM3pxl5QV9Y8KU2smqmXpYEt2j4UJwtzDXCp5tzghkNb/Y@vK@DzEJknA5L035ZuPsD)

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 74 bytes

Takes input as `(gold, silver, bronze, 'rep')`. Returns a Boolean value.

```javascript
(g,s,b,r)=>(F=s=>[...s].sort()+0)(r)==F([g,g,g,s,s,b].filter(x=>x).join``)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZFNbsMgEIX3PUV2gEqRMYyywkufoLs0UtzUdhxZpgK3Sk/vDqaLVIbwIyTeNzOP4dp8N/7shs/5ZbIf7dKZhfbc83fumKlobbypDkIIfxTeupmy54JRlExNDz0P0wf6KLphnFtHb6a6MXG1w3Q6seVsJ2/HVoy2p@TVfc2XH8Ke7m87WvAdLs13RBOWEFGRe1Sl1vstoNfoFdCPiDU/jmQJiAwCAFsAVlGhDiqjqxiPuoJkheAAR9ZENBA96FwGWaqQIRzZIqqUd8g/hrxNdTP67Q/ImD1rLjYAILwQUh3A0FLFHj8yF54nk6L820QWRVgILb8)

Answer (score 7):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>28 bytes</s> <s>20 bytes</s> <s>16 bytes</s> 13 bytes

Returns 0 for false and 1 for true. This can definitely be golfed down.

```
[1,3,2,1]Y"t2:7)XzVXzY@Ums0>
```

Down to 16 bytes if the reputation score can be taken in separately, and the order is [bronze, silver, gold], reputation
Down to 13 bytes thanks to Luis Mendo

```
3:Y"XzVXzY@Um
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8N/YKlIpoiosoirSITT3v0vI/2hDcx0THYNYLkMTE3OuaEMdAx3DWC4TIAAA)

Answer (score 7):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s><sup>38</sup></s> <s><sup>34</sup></s> <s><sup>31</sup></s> 20 bytes

```
-:&(\:~&.":)]#~#\.**
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZHBqgIxDEX3fsVFQd@IDs00YaDgSnDlyrVv9VDEjX/gr49JJx2rL3QgnHu5TTP3Yd6urtglrLBBQNJv22J/Oh6GbVr@nNNz2c5T87t4Ls7tej00s8vf7QEiEbLCVXsIaOSxU9YZRIfo3qDl1qD5FErGO0D5bKSswFyMsdzL3GeBQf1Ee2YyP1tqXyhrOeR3ArNIThATCpWYqSiKqGkccay8npuHs3aiflmo5@1i8eb2H2XdFPzJAbsSbpug@uGmiUxDavOpeaSuO/rKKs3vCgC@M/Wn2MkOymd4AQ)

*-11 bytes thanks to FrownyFrog!*

Comment: [20 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZZHBasMwEETv/orBhsQ2iaq1VhjUGgKFnnrqNempNA259A/y6@5KXjlqu8iwvBlGq/V1rs32jClgix0sgnx7g@e315d5HzbtKdw2pg7dsbk1J9P3c1d9TQYOAwjtMeAR7dOhQd@I6aGmw850eK@qz4/LN4i8p1g4Sw8PWrgbhA0RSoxTr5VSq5UhyOaMe4BwTWYB0cVYSr3MYxIYNK50ZKbo55g6ZspSCvmewOx9SvBRyNS7RL0gh5K6BbvCq7lpuNiuVC@z5byDy97U/qMsm4I@2WLK4XETVD48at6vQ0rzW9NIWbfTlRWa3mUB/M2UnxJPclA68w8)

Comment: well 19, since you can take the medals reversed.

Comment: That is a seriously nice golf.  Tyvm!  I especially like the use of `&.` to remove the spaces.  Great trick.

Answer (score 6):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 69 bytes

```ruby
->r,g,s,b{([g,g,g,s,s,b]-[0]).flat_map(&:digits).sort==r.digits.sort}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY/daoQwEIXvfYpcSNGSTRMzQSjYFwlB3K5mXdxdSbItpfTZbX7UQocJzPk4c4aYx/FrGZrl8GawxhYfvwupsY6zV@ogqSrJMHWuvXZz8fR6GvXobEns3bimMSTpKH@Wz/M49Uj3zmZoNuPNobwl7@f7dSbT5WFdUbESo0E@9x/dVORtqTDKX7L@dlokYERjg8okA6iTwIjVHtQADKKkKwFfG4CohYhCBOaB4AEkxpPmCfBkSAnrUV8JbZnBwSq@O8L8DwGv2J7DkiscEn@Hhdh3vKHi6/e2hHiE0tBpPT71Cw)

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>14</s> <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
íp fn ¬á øUg
```

Takes input as `[rep, bronze, silver, gold]`

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=7XAgZm4grOEg%2bFVn&input=WyI0IiwiNCIsIjAiLCIwIl0) or [Verify all test cases](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LW1S&code=VD1VzlXF1HVUIO1wIGZuIKzhIPhVZw&input=WwpbIjQiLCAiMCIsICIwIiwgIjQiXSwKWyIxNDQ3IiwgIjAiLCAiNCIsICIxNyJdLApbIjQxNDQ3IiwgIjQiLCAiMCIsICIxNyJdLApbIjQ0NDQiLCAiNCIsICIwIiwgIjQiXSwKWyI0NDU1IiwgIjAiLCAiNTQiLCAiMCJdLApbIjUzNTUiLCAiNSIsICIwIiwgIjMiXSwKWyI1MzUzNSIsICI1IiwgIjMiLCAiMCJdLApbIjQ0NDQiLCAiMCIsICIwIiwgIjQ0NDQiXSwKWyI0NDQiLCAiNCIsICIwIiwgIjAiXSwKWyIxMjM0IiwgIjAiLCAiMCIsICIxMjM0Il0sClsiMTIzNCIsICIwIiwgIjAiLCAiNDMyMSJdLAoKWyI0NDQ0IiwgIjEiLCAiMCIsICIxIl0sClsiNTU1NSIsICI1IiwgIjAiLCAiNTUiXSwKWyIxMjM0IiwgIjEiLCAiMjMiLCAiNCJdLApbIjEiLCAiMCIsICIwIiwgIjAiXSwKWyIxMDAxMDAxIiwgIjAiLCAiMTAiLCAiMTAiXQpd)

```
Sample input: U = [1447, 17, 4, 0]
íp            Repeats each value of U by it's index amount e.g. ["","17","44","000"]
  fn          Remove all falsy values when converted to a number e.g. ["17","44"]
    ¬         Concatenate e.g. "1744"
     á        All permutations e.g. ["1744","1744","1474","1447","1474","1447","7144","7144","7414","7441","7414","7441","4174","4147","4714","4741","4417","4471","4174","4147","4714","4741","4417","4471"]
      øUg     Does it contain the first item of the input?
```

Comment: I've taken a few stabs at this from a couple of different angles but can't do better than 13 either.

Comment: @Shaggy Turns out the `Å` was unnecessary, since `fn` would get rid of the first value. Removing `Å` makes it 12 bytes

Comment: This is 16 bytes in utf-8, not 12 bytes.

Comment: @LieRyan Some golfing languages use their own encodings; Japt uses ISO-8859-1`

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance, Ah, goddamnit, why didn't I spot that?! I really do feel so out of practice since I took that month off for my open bounty for Japt.

Answer (score 5):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 45 bytes

```
,0
,
,(\d*),(\d*),
¶$1$1$1$2$2
%O`.
^(.+)¶\1$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5BDsJACEX3nGOatEqaYYD0CC69QGNqogs3Loxn6wF6sSkwNQKZvA8fMp/n9/W@166/LBUzIGA/P07D8cK2JoosqUB3XUa49eN52NaZUq2C2VKARCYHpAkkhE9cWASLoaqBmgJlY1fsyM5s7XDHRQv4rWagwq3v8FfChdoO@QxUj6uqzURY2H8XbjuTs5d7vXY) Link includes test suite. Explanation:

```
,0
,
```

Delete zero scores.

```
,(\d*),(\d*),
¶$1$1$1$2$2
```

Expand the gold and silver scores, and convert the separator to a newline.

```
%O`.
```

Sort the reputation and the expanded scores separately.

```
^(.+)¶\1$
```

Compare the sorted digits.

Answer (score 5):

### Racket, <s>149</s> <s>107</s> 98 bytes

```lisp
(λ(r b s g[h(λ x(sort(string->list(apply ~a(remq*'(0)x)))char<?))])(equal?(h r)(h b s s g g g)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZFLTsQwDIb3PYUlFthISEnjqBvEHASxCENfopROGqRhw8W4A1cqSZOOoC1JZCv67N92Ys3xpXTTVWf6Gux8yfC5rNq@hGrC7y@08AQj1A@Nv8AZxzfrcHS27evb@64dHZph6D7g06AtX0831yjoTETHxti7A9EjYXl6N90BG7DkTVDzemH7sImyDAev5roesAKGuGYv/CH6wyVzEZAsYtCaF8ySF@7zecXZr9/6W651QgCaN/paRa5SkN5ypZd8teWX@sHvzJdwzN/pT@ZqDpj93vskziqXC99tQKYCcj2AjgNqvT/gpUAwudrky/SB4r8PFCIc70MTIvDpBw)

First time golfing in Racket, so still looking for improvements...

Explanation (of the original longer version, but same idea):

```lisp
(λ(r b                              ; take rep and badges as arguments
     [g(λ(x)                        ; helper function g which takes a string
         (sort                      ; and returns the sorted
           (string->list x)         ; list of characters
           char<?))])               ; (sort by ascii code)
  (equal?                           ; compare...
    (g(~a r))                       ; g called on the rep converted to string
    (g                              ; and g called on...
      (string-join                  ; the concatenation of
        (map ~a                     ; the stringified elements of
             (append*               ; the flattened list given by
               (filter              ; the elements of the following list where
                 (λ(x)(>(car x)0))  ; the badge count is nonzero:
                 (map make-list     ; repeat the badge counts
                      '(1 2 3)b)))) ; 1, 2, and 3 times respectively
        ""))))
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
xJ$¹ƇV,Ṣ€E
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/CS@XQzmPtYToPdy561LTG9f///9GGBjoKIGwQ@9/QwACEAA)

Argument 1: `[Bronze, Silver, Gold]`
Argument 2: `Rep`

Comment: This is 16 bytes in utf-8, not 10 bytes.

Comment: @LieRyan Jelly uses [a custom code page](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki/Code-page).

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 24 bytes

```
1Ｆ⁴Ｆ↨ＮχＦι⊞υκＦχ¿⁻№υι№θＩι⎚
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYy7DoMwDEX3fsUVkyNRCUSZ2MrUoYhfSFEQUdOkTWJ@P7X6sAdf6@jcZdNxCdqVMkfrM1VtpYbDGiLopPC5Z50MXfyT88SPm4mkarSN@lGrMHPaiGvc/6ZQ2BV0tZ4TjYGlWLgV8fu8JOiURZbB6IyW1qGUvpNFgw59Oe7uDQ) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input in the order rep, bronze, silver, gold and outputs `1` if the rep is valid. Explanation:

```
1
```

Assume the rep is valid.

```
Ｆ⁴Ｆ↨ＮχＦι⊞υκ
```

Loop over the four input values. Push each digit of each value `i` times where `i` is the 0-indexed index of the value. Numeric base conversion is used here as that converts `0` to an empty array.

```
Ｆχ¿⁻№υι№θＩι⎚
```

Check the count of each digit in the array matches that in the first input. If any differ, clear the canvas.

Comment: This is 60 bytes in utf-8, not 24 bytes.

Comment: @LieRyan I didn't say they were UTF-8 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 18 bytes

```
DẋṠƊ€ẋ"3RU¤FṢ⁼⁴DṢ¤
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/l4a7uhzsXHOt61LQGyFQyDgo9tMTt4c5Fjxr3PGrc4gJkHVry//9/Ax0FEx0FQ/P/hiYm5gA)

this is a *bit* bad

Comment: This is 37 bytes in utf-8, not 18 bytes.

Comment: @LieRyan Jelly (and many other golfing languages) use their own code page such that all 256 1-byte codes correspond to one of the characters used by the language.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>80</s> <s>79</s> <s>77</s> 68 bytes

```python
lambda r,g,s,b:S((g>0)*3*`g`+(s>0)*2*`s`+(b>0)*`b`)==S(`r`)
S=sorted
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYsxDsMgEAR7v4ISyBXHoTSRyCdoU5yRYxIpsS2g8esJuHC0u9JIo9328loXqrN71M/4DdMoEkTIEG5eynhHpa3myBeZO5Pm3Dh05sDKOS85sRq8y2sqz6lu6b0UMUtjyCAiWRAGgcCq4VSIvSDwcG1/d7UtIFrbEVX9AQ)

Takes input as `rep, gold, silver, bronze`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-lF`, 62 bytes

```perl
map{@r=sort/./g,@r if($_=<>x$_)>0}1..3;@F=sort@F;say"@r"eq"@F"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83saDaoci2OL@oRF9PP13HoUghM01DJd7Wxq5CJV7TzqDWUE/P2NrBDazEwc26OLFSyaFIKbVQycFN6f9/cxMTQxMuQ3MuAy6Tf/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwMDf7r5rgBAA)

Takes input on separate lines as

```perl
reputation
bronze
silver
gold
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 10 bytes

```
€mdPfIṁdṘN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HTmtyUgDTPhzsbUx7unOH3////aENzHRMdg9j/hiYm5gA)

Similar to the Japt answer.

Takes `[bronze,silver,gold]` as first argument, `rep` as second argument.

### Explanation

```
€mdPfIṁdṘN  
         N natural numbers
        Ṙ  repeat medals that many times
      ṁd   get all their digits as a single array
    fI     filter out zeroes
   P       permutations
 md        mapped to their base-10 numbers
€          is rep in the list?
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 66 <s>69</s> bytes

<sup>-3 bytes thanks to mazzy</sup>

```powershell
''+($args|%{"$_"*$i++*!!$_}|% t*y|sort)-eq(''+$args[0]|% t*y|sort)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZLBasMwDIbP81OombvaSQp2bBMYdMc9wW6jlB7SbZDRLekYo8mzZ7YcN04rHBB8/y9Zkb@Ov1XTvld1PdDD5jysVhmj@@at7ZbnhO6SlH5kWbpY0F3fLeGU/nXtsTnxdfXNrBSVr2Ibo6EnhH7CBhhhOgeBR/McfNyvn@Cl@akIk1qXHuYgSxRMsNRaakQi0AlqG4GNlWNoDBLjBFdljXLQc3XttFB5qm6dvuc4jQ2LZzDcR4yTRnMW6uJ0@cwZQ60KGcPQVHpr@IWOP@/r1t3YTOMYE3Ueua9u/YWadhDz0Fpc9jPnQrjj@@PHecTtnu0zIXcJZXRnnwEHTFRIipDILX@EBDJgD/QAqAUUAqrAS0g//AM)

Takes input at (Rep, Bronze, Silver, Gold)

Figure I'll take a crack at my own question. Converts the numbers `toCharArray`s and sorts them. Appends an empty string so the sorted arrays are converted back to space-separated strings which can then be compared.

We handle 0 medal counts with `!!$_` which doubly negates the number, making it go `non-zero number-> 0 -> 1` or `0 -> 1 -> 0` which is used to blank the repeat counter.

Comment: you can remove second `''+`. because Powershell implicitly brings the type of second operand to the type of first operand.

Answer (score 1):

## Wolfram Language (Mathematica), <s>69</s> 68 bytes

```
i=IntegerDigits
Sort@i@#==Sort[Join@@i/@Select[{##2,##3,#4},#!=0&]]&
```

Defines an anonymous function; takes inputs to function as [reputation, bronze, silver, gold].

I think this method for repeating silver and gold is interesting (and unique among these answers): in an anonymous function, `#n` represents argument n and `##n` represents a sequence of arguments from argument n to the end, so if one were to expand `{##2,##3,#4}`, it would become `{#2,#3,#4,#3,#4,#4}`, which repeats each the necessary number of times while being 7 bytes less than the expanded form.